# Negative Divergence of Radial Vector Fields?

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble understanding the concept of divergence with respect to a set of cases: radial vector fields (in 2d, for the sake of simplicity.)  If we write the vector field as (x,y)/r^n, where r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2), the divergence varies in sign with respect to n.  As n increases to 2, the divergence passes through zero and becomes negative everywhere.

But I don't understand how a vector field that is always pointing out from the origin can have negative divergence.  Doesn't a negative divergence indicate, in the case of fluid flow, that the fluid is "entering" a point rather than "leaving" it?  But clearly this is not the case near the origin, for example, where in every direction the vectors are pointing away from the origin?  I don't understand what is special about the magnitude of the vectors decreasing more quickly away from the origin (which is what happens as n increases).

Note: I understand the case where n < 0.  I am only considering the cases where n > 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Doesn't a negative divergence indicate, in the case of fluid flow, that the fluid is "entering" a point rather than "leaving" it?

Yes, or perhaps saying the fluid is compressed at that point is better.

> But clearly this is not the case near the origin, for example, where in every direction the vectors are pointing away from the origin?

You need to distinguish between the origin itself, and points near the origin.

The origin is a singularity of the field (for $n \geqslant 1$, the field isn't even continuous at the origin, and for $n > 1$ not even bounded), it is a point source, fluid is created ex nihilo there.

For other points than the origin, in the case of a radial field (whose magnitude only depends on the distance from the origin), it is perhaps best to consider a small annulus (or, in dimensions $> 2$, a spherical shell) centered at the origin containing the point. A negative divergence in that annulus says that the fluid flows into the annulus (shell) faster through the inner bounding circle (sphere) than it flows out through the outer bounding circle (shell).

That that happens when the speed decreases fast enough with increasing distance from the source is, I think, understandable.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it.  So, with the case n = 2, would you say that the reason the divergence is 0 everywhere is that while the fluid is indeed flowing with less intensity farther from the origin, the fact that it is still flowing out in a moderate number directions offsets this?

In other words, that the direction of flow in a radial vector field contributes to a positive divergence, while the diminution with respect to the distance from the origin contributes to a negative divergence?

Comment: The area the fluid has to cover when travelling the same radial distance increases. Infinitesimally, proportional to the distance from the origin, so the flow is compression-free when the speed is inversely proportional to the distance from the origin, that is $n = 2$. If the speed decreases faster, the fluid is compressed, if slower, the fluid expands.

Comment: Do you mean "inversely proportional to the SQUARE of the distance from the origin"?  And I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "the area the fluid has to cover when traveling the same radial distance increases."  Do you mean that the area it covers increases when the radial distance increases?

Comment: No, not the square. Remember that you have a factor $r$ in $(x,y)$, so $n = 2$ means the speed is proportional to $r^{-1}$. When the fluid travels the radial distance $h$ starting from $r_0$, it covers the annulus $r_0 \leqslant \lvert (x,y)\rvert \leqslant r_0+h$, and the area of that annulus is $\pi\left((r_0+h)^2 - r_0^2\right) = \pi(2r_0h + h^2)$, and it increases with $r_0$. Writing $h = v\cdot \Delta t$ with the speed $v$, we see that the area is constant with respect to time (infinitesimally) when $v\cdot r_0 \equiv \text{ const}$.

Comment: First, sorry about my n = 2 mistake; that was silly.  I understand how this is significant in the case vr = const., but I'm not sure I understand how the area of the annulus is significant in general.  Regarding flux I see its relevance, but not with divergence.  Doesn't divergence - being a quasi-derivative - only concern a single point and those points very near it?  So the area of the annulus would be irrelevant?

Comment: No sweat about the square thing, a normal mistake. In _general_, you're right, the annulus isn't relevant. But here we have a special situation, a field of the form $F(x) = \varphi(r)\cdot \frac{x}{r}$, radial, and the speed depends only on $r$. So you have a nice symmetry about the origin, and then things are easier to calculate (and visualize?) when you only consider symmetric situations. If you want to consider only small neighbourhoods of points (other than the origin), calculations are still easier when you take an angular sector of the annulus. If you have a radial field where the ...

Comment: ... speed depends not only on the radius, $F(x) = \psi(x)\cdot \frac{x}{r}$, with $\psi \colon \mathbb{R}^n(\setminus \{0\}) \to \mathbb{R}$ not rotationally symmetric, then things change, and looking at such an annulus doesn't help, then you need to look locally.

Comment: Do you mind evaluating the statement I made earlier, just so I know that I'm not tripping myself up still?  "The direction of flow in a radial vector field contributes to a positive divergence, while the diminution with respect to the distance from the origin contributes to a negative divergence?"  Thanks for all of the help, by the way.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure I understand correctly what you mean. But if I do, then yes, that's right, the directional component, $\frac{x}{r}$ contributes $\frac{d-1}{r}$ to the divergence (multiplied with the magnitude $\varphi(r)$, $d$ is the dimension of the space), and the change of magnitude contributes $\varphi'(r)$. (In the case that the magnitude depends only on $r$, otherwise it's a combination of the radial derivative and the tangential derivatives.) So if the flow is away from the origin ($\varphi > 0$), the directional part contributes to a positive divergence.

Comment: I've just worked it all out following your guideline, and it works perfectly.  Working with phi = r^k, we find the divergence has two terms: one from the direction (as you wrote it) and one from the magnitude, which reduces over the sum simply to k*r^(k-1).  So the divergence is r^(k-1)*(k + n - 1), which equals zero iff k = 1-n.  In our n = 2 example, k = -1, which corresponds with the div = 0 case we discussed earlier.  Thanks a lot!  Breaking down the divergence into these two components (one from the direction, the other from the magnitude) really did it for me.